# Foreach in foreach [PHP]

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

Actually I work with PHP framework Codeigniter and I want to compare value from first `foreach` to second one, but I'm getting an error. Example here:

```
<?php foreach($posts->result() as $post): ?>

    (html content) 

    <?php foreach($tags->result() as $tag) { 
        if($tag->id_users ==  $post->id_users) echo $tag->tag_name; 
    } ?>

    (html content) 

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

When I compare `$post->id_users` inner second `foreach` I'm getting error, how can I get around this?

Comment: Add one more closing curly braces after if block.

Comment: Okay, you're getting an error - but what exactly is that error? You need to include it in your question.

Comment: You shouldn't mix the normal and alternate syntaxes like that. Either use one or the other. Using both makes your code hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to avoid loop inside a loop

```
$tag_ids = array();
foreach($tags->result() as $tag) { 
    $tag_ids[] = $tag->id_users;
}

foreach ($posts->result() as $key => $post) {
    if(in_array($post->id_users, $tag_ids)) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't close the second foreach. For eg

```
<?php foreach($posts->result() as $post): ?> foreach1 

    (...some html) 

    <?php foreach($tags->result() as $tag) { if($tag->id_users == $post->id_users) echo $tag->tag_name; } ?>  //foreach2 

        (...some html) 

    <?php endforeach; ?> 

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `$posts->result()` and `$tags->result()` inside foreach loop. Because it will go to check for every time while foreach is live.
Overall it decrease the performance of script.

```
<?php
$posts = $posts->result();
$tags = $tags->result();

foreach($posts as $post) {
?>
    << Other HTML code goes here >>
    <?php
    foreach($tags as $tag) {
        if($tag->id_users ==  $post->id_users) {
             echo $tag->tag_name;
        }
    ?>
        << Other HTML code >>
    <?php
    }
}
```